# How can I make my label's width grow, so they fill up the HBox - javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2, fxml

So my problem is I can't get my label's width to grow with the HBox in JavaFX.

Here is a [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekhwi.png).
I want the red to fill the whole width, here is my code:

```
<VBox id="taskBar" fx:id="fx_taskBar" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: yellow;">
           <children>
              <StackPane prefWidth="600.0">
                 <children>
                    <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: green;">
                       <children>
                          <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="70.0" styleClass="task_text" stylesheets="@taskBar.css" text="+" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                             <font>
                                <Font size="24.0" />
                             </font>
                          </Label>
                          <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="115.0" styleClass="task_text" stylesheets="@taskBar.css" text="+">
                             <font>
                                <Font size="24.0" />
                             </font>
                          </Label>
                          <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="55.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="121.0" styleClass="task_text" stylesheets="@taskBar.css" text="+">
                             <font>
                                <Font size="24.0" />
                             </font>
                          </Label>
                          <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="170.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="132.0" styleClass="task_text" stylesheets="@taskBar.css" text="+">
                             <font>
                                <Font size="24.0" />
                             </font>
                          </Label>
                          <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="291.0" layoutY="10.0" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="170.0" styleClass="task_text" stylesheets="@taskBar.css" text="+" HBox.hgrow="NEVER">
                             <font>
                                <Font size="24.0" />
                             </font>
                          </Label>
                       </children>
                    </HBox>
                 </children>
              </StackPane>
           </children>
        </VBox>
```

Comment: I've never seen java that looks like this, but that could just be my own inexperience. However, are you sure this is not javascript?

Comment: @DavyM Don't worry, this isn't javascript.

Comment: @DavyM this is JavaFX FXML

Comment: add priority to them (`Label`)? `Priority.ALWAYS` or `Priority.SOMETIMES`. the second might fit your preference best

Comment: @Elltz How should I add that I am using SceneBuilder to build the UI? (New in JavaFX)

Comment: Set the label's `maxWidth` to `MAX_VALUE` (as well as setting the `vgrow` to `ALWAYS`).

Comment: Furthermore fon't set `layoutX`/`layoutY` yourself, if the parent node asigns those positions during a layout pass. Setting the properties will have no effect. Also I recommend adding the stylesheet to the `HBox` (or some ancestor) instead of adding it to every single `Label`. Of course this only works if you properly distinguish the `Label`s from other nodes, but since you're assigning a style class... `contentDisplay` determines the placement of the `graphic`, should there be one. It's unnecessary here.